# Games to learn Chinese with?

Tags: resources, games

I’ve been looking online for the bigger part of a day in search of **roleplaying** games in Chinese for helping me learn it more efficiently.

I also asked my girlfriend (Chinese) to help me find a game like that, but the only game we found was only available on iOS on the Chinese App Store.

Do you guys know of any rpg’s that I can get in Chinese?

Edit: I’m a (total) beginner at Chinese. I also only have apple products and a ps4.

Comment: Perhaps you could also look for games that are translated to Chinese? I don't play much games at all but the only game I played, Monument Vally, has good Chinese translations.

Comment: You might want to mention these, you current Chinese level, preferred os (ios? android, pc...), preferred type of game, I'd like to introduce some for you if you can describe more.

Comment: Why not most RPGs that has English voice but Chinese subtitles? You know, try to map the English into Chinese yourself then look if the subtitle is doing better.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for "御龙在天" in the major Android application market, such as Huawei application market, Xiaomi application market, 360 mobile assistant, tappap, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try WeGame (PC platform) or Steam?
Some games are built by native Chinese developers while some other games received decent translation (which is more helpful), for example, Pillars of Eternity II and many games from Ubisoft.

On Wegame platform, it is almost guaranteed a well-made Chinese translation but English text might be absent.  But you might have trouble with payment.

In general, I suggest you search Steam to find games with good Chinese translation (please enable Chinese reviews to see if it is well translated).  (if you are not sure, 3A game are a better choice since their publisher/developer have a better ability for localization)

If you are interested in traditional Chinese culture as well, you can search games with “武侠”, “仙侠” elements.